# react-native - Problem with compiling the iOS application - IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

Tags: xcode, react-native

I get this message when trying to compile an iOS application. Has anyone had a similar problem?

> Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of
> supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.0.99.

Could someone give me some advice because I'm stuck and I don't know what to do.

I've tried similar solutions from the internet, but they all involve older versions.

I have it set in xcode: minimum Deployments 12.4

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your Podfile, remove Pods folder and do `pod install`

```html
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    end
  end
end
```